# Delete an Open Graph Page when I delete the corresponding article

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to delete an Open Graph Facebook Page ?

I want to delete them when I delete an article on my website, so users won't be confused when trying to find a product that's no longer available.

---

*Edit :*

I already tried `DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=...` with an admin access token (with manage_pages extended permission) or with page access token, but I only get an "**Unsupported delete request.**" error message

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner and creator of the page, you could try issuing a HTTP DELETE command to the page id, eg:

DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=... HTTP/1.1

You will want to make sure that the access token you use has manage_pages extended permission.  I am not 100% sure pages can be deleted but all deletes work the same with the graph API and that is how you delete comments, posts, etc.

Comment: I already tried that with an admin access token (with manage_pages extended permission) or with page access token, but I only get an "Unsupported delete request." error message

Comment: Then you are unable to delete them via the graph api as I expected.